Project Server Force Checkin
I am working on an admin force checkin and publish of a checked out project in ProjectOnline
If the project is not Checked out, I can achieve a Publish as follows
$projecRef = $projContext.Projects.GetById($projId)
$draftProj = $projecRef.CheckOut()
$draftProj.Publish($true)
$projContext.ExecuteQuery()

But how do I do the same if the project is already checked out by another user. I would like to Force a check-in
The Checkin method for DraftProject has a force parameter. But how do I get a reference to the already checked out DraftProject? Or is there another scripted way to do this?
In the old scheme with PSI, you could do the following
$svcPSProxy = New-WebServiceProxy -uri ($PWAUrl + "/_vti_bin/PSI/Project.asmx?wsdl") -useDefaultCredential 
$svcPSProxy.QueueCheckInProject([System.Guid]::NewGuid() , $projId, "true",[System.Guid]::NewGuid(),"Automatic checkin")
$svcPSProxy.QueuePublish([System.Guid]::NewGuid(), $projId, "true","")

How can I do the same with ProjectOnline?
Thanks in advance!

This turned out to be easier than I thought
using (ProjectContext projContext = new ProjectContext("https://mycompany.sharepoint.com/sites/pwa")) //PWAURL
{
    SecureString password = new SecureString();
    foreach (char c in "password".ToCharArray()) password.AppendChar(c);
    projContext.Credentials = new SharePointOnlineCredentials("account@mycompany.com", password);
    csom.PublishedProject project = projContext.Projects.GetByGuid(new Guid("12345678-f579-4ca4-85f2-75dabcd12311"));
    csom.JobState jobState = projContext.WaitForQueue(project.Draft.CheckIn(true), 60);
}

